# Upper bounding trace of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $[E]_{n\times n}$ be a symmetric positive semi definite matrix, and let $[X]_{n\times j}$ a matrix having orthonormal columns then, the problem is to give an upper and lower bound on the expression  $\text {Tr}\, ( XX^TE).$

Answer (score 2):

You have $$\text {Tr}\, (XX^TE)=\text {Tr}\, (X^TEX)\geq0. $$ And $$0\leq\text {Tr}\, (X^TEX)\leq\|E\|\,\text {Tr}\, ( X^TX)=n\|E\|. $$ We can get a similar estimate, in the other direction, with the smallest eigenvalue of $E $.

In summary, if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_n $ are the biggest and smallest eigenvalues of $E $, we get
$$ n\lambda_n \leq\text {Tr}\, (XX^TE)\leq n\lambda_1. $$

Comment: thanks for your response. One clarification, how did we get $Tr(X^TEX)\leq ||E||Tr(X^X)$, and $||E||$ denote spectral norm or forb norm of $E$? Also $Tr(X^TX)=j?$

Comment: It's the spectral norm; in this case, the largest eigenvalue. You have $E\leq\| E\|\,I$, and conjugation and the trace preserve operator inequalities. As for $:-$ versus $:-$, you said in another comment that $X^TX=I_n$. If it's $j$, I'll change it.